# How to get value of checkbox from checkboxlistFor using jquery ajax in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I have a `checkboxlistfor` control in mvc 5 and want the value of the selected checkbox, once I get the value then send ajax request and fetch the data as per id,
below is the reference link where similar kind of functionality is achieved, in this he has used "for loop" for multiple checkboxes, and I am using checkboxlistfor, using this I am not able to get the value of the selected checkbox.

"https://forums.asp.net/t/2078931.aspx?How+to+get+data+from+checkbox+list+using+jquery+ajax+in+MVC+"

Below is the code I am using to bind checkboxlistfor code

view

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.sbuIDs, 
                      model => model.Availablesbu,
                      sb => sb.sbuID,
                      sb => sb.sbuName,
                      model => model.Selectedsbu,
                      htmlListInfo)
```

controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddUsers()
{
    var Uvm = new UsersViewModel();

    var Selectedsbu = new List<sbu>();
    Uvm.Availablesbu = _User.Getallsbu();
    Uvm.Selectedsbu = Selectedsbu;
    return View(Uvm);
}

public class sbu
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int sbuID { get; set; }
    public string sbuName { get; set; }
}

public class UsersViewModel()
{
    public IEnumerable<sbu> sbu = null;
    sbu = new List<sbu>();
    public IEnumerable<sbu> Availablesbu { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<sbu> Selectedsbu { get; set; }
    public string[] sbuIDs { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

Below is the ajax request i will use:

```
<script>
    $("#CheckBoxListFor").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input[name='sbuIDs']:checked"), function () {
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '@Url.Action("Getvalues", "Home")',

            data: JSON.stringify({ values: favorite })
        });

    });
</script>
```

Controller code

```
public JsonResult Getvalues(string[] values)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: The relevant parts here are going to the the AJAX and the actual HTML markup of your checkbox and the code of the controller that is accepting the AJAX call. Can you please add that to your question.

Comment: i have not yet added any ajax call , as i am not able to fetch the id of the selected checkbox, if i some how get the code of getting id on click event  of checkbox inside checkboxlistfor then i will handle the ajax request.

Comment: I am not familiar with the CheckBoxListFor using the parameters you are passing. Rendered html will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendered in HTML a check box list will have a shared name but will have different ids being the name followed by a `-` and a number identifying the index.

You can use jQuery to get a list of those selected.

```
$('[name="checkBoxListName"]:checked');
```

To get an array of their values:

```
var values = $('[name="checkBoxListName"]:checked').get();
```

Your sample script should work with some minor changes. 1) use the name selector as your checkboxes will have different ids. 2) Wrap the code in `$(document).ready`. 3) Just post the raw object and not a string:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name='checkBoxListName']).change(function () {
        // code here.
        data: { values: favorite }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thakyou i will try this and add comments...looks like it will help me..

Comment: Thank you it helped

Answer (score 0):

Below is the ajax request i have use

```
<script>
                            $("#CheckBoxListFor").change(function () {
                                debugger;
                                var favorite = [];
                                $.each($("input[name='sbuIDs']:checked"), function () {
                                    favorite.push($(this).val());
                                });

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: "application/json",
                                    url: '@Url.Action("Getvalues", "Home")',

                                    data: JSON.stringify({ values: favorite })
                                });

                            });



                        </script>
```

Controller code

```
 public JsonResult Getvalues(string[] values)
    {
```

....
}

Comment: I moved the code to your question and put modifications in my answer.